# Array copy functor example: improvement/alternative?

Tags: c++

**Problem**

Implement a copy functor 'interface' that works with both scalars and arrays.

```
CopyFunctor::operator()(T& dest, const T& src);
```

As an example, I want to generalize a sort function to work with both array of elements and array of 'inlined' arrays.

```
template <typename T, typename CopyFunctor> sort(T array[]);

int array_of_elements[] = {7, 3, 5, 2};
sort(array_of_elements);
// after sorting: {2, 3, 5, 7}

int array_of_arrays[] = {  3, 1,   2, 4,   7, 6,   5, 8};
// inlined arrays are: {3, 1}, {2, 4}, {7, 6}, {5, 8}
// these 'inlined' arrays are fixed-sized
// after sorting using first element as key: { 2, 4,   3, 1,   5, 8,    7, 6}   
// thus, the second element should be moved with the first element
```

Inside sort(T array[]), 
to swap element (or group of elements) from position i to position j,
we can call the functor in exactly the same manner regardless whether a is an array of elements or an array of 'inlined arrays':

```
template <typename T, typename CopyFunctor> sort(T array[], CopyFunctor copy) {

 // ...

   // swap a[i] and a[j]
   copy(b, a[i]);
   copy(a[i], a[j]);
   copy(a[j], b);

 // ...

 }
```

Here b is either a scalar or an array large enough to hold one 'inlined' array of within a.
(For this example, I'd probably want a swap functor instead, but in my more complicated use case, I needed a copy functor.)

**Assumptions**

Once the array of inlined arrays is initialized, it will *never* be resized.

**Example code**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct ScalarSetter {
    void operator()(T& a, const T& b) const {
        a = b;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct ArraySetter {
    size_t _n;
    ArraySetter(size_t n) : _n(n) {}
    void operator()(T& a, const T& b) const {
        std::memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(T)*_n);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    {
      ScalarSetter<float> copy;
      float a = 1.0;
      float b = 2.0;
      copy(a, b);
      printf("a = %f\n", a);
      /* output:
       * a = 2.00000
       */
    }

    {
      size_t n = 3;
      ArraySetter<float> copy(n);
      float c[] = {.1, .2, .3, .4};
      float d[] = {.4, .5, .6, .7};
      copy(c[0], d[0]);
      for (size_t i = 0; i < n+1; ++i) {
        printf("c[%d] = %f\n", i, c[i]);
      }
      /* output:
       * c[0] = 0.400000
       * c[1] = 0.500000
       * c[2] = 0.600000
       * c[3] = 0.400000
       */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Since I am actually using Cuda/C++, I am more or less forced to use inlined arrays.

The example code above compiles, runs, and passes valgrind memory test.
But I feel a tad uncomfortable derving pointers to the input arguments in ArraySetter::operator()(...).

(*Edit*: I think the code will break if an inlined array is not contiguous... Is there any guarantee on the contiguity of (dynamically) allocated arrays?)

Is there another way of implmenting a consistent copy functor 'interface' that works with both scalars and arrays?

Comment: Could it be that you simply want a matrix class? You can implement them as `inlined arrays` and have a nice high-level interface for row swapping etc.

Comment: What about having your array as: `int array[2][] = { {3,1}, {2,4} ...};`? The memory layout will be the same, and if you pass that to sort it will operate on `int[2]` (untested)

Comment: “functor” usually denotes something else in C++. It’s also not clear what you actually need this for. Your `copy` function seems to fulfil the role of the assignment operator – so why not simply use the latter?

Comment: @Rodriguez  That's how I usually work with arrays in C++. But since I am programming for GPU, I think I am more or less stuck with inlined arrays for performance reason.

Comment: @pmr That will work, though the client function will need to handle the matrix class differently from a native array, I think.

Comment: @Rudolph Sorry for the confusion. I edited my comments. Now in all cases, 'copy' is actually a functor and not a function.